# Is possible to play audio from AudioQueue in real time?

Tags: objective-c, ios, networking, tcp, audioqueue

I need to get audio from microphone and pass to other device using tcp connection.
I not sure if is possible to play an AudioBuffer from the AudioQueue.

Currently I'm get the buffer with the code below:

```
  void AudioInputCallback(
    void *inUserData, 
    AudioQueueRef inAQ, 
    AudioQueueBufferRef inBuffer, 
    const AudioTimeStamp *inStartTime, 
    UInt32 inNumberPacketDescriptions, 
    const AudioStreamPacketDescription *inPacketDescs)
  {
    AudioRecorder *self = (AudioRecorder *)inUserData;

    if(!self.recordState.recording)
    {
      NSLog(@"[ AudioRecorder ] AudioInputCallback not recording");
      return;
    }

    if(inNumberPacketDescriptions > 0)
    {
      NSData *data =  [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:inBuffer->mAudioData length:inBuffer->mAudioDataByteSize * 2];
      [self.delegate didReceivedAudioData:data];
      [data release];
    }

  }
```

This block just push mAudioData to NSData, the NSData is the key data type to transfer data between devices.

Now I don't know how to run this mAudioData in other device. Other thing is how to get audio continuously, when all buffers are full, I not receive data anymore, just need to clean the buffer I guess.

Any idea are welcome, thanks!